# How to stop quartz scheduler externally which is running from main method

Tags: java, jar, quartz-scheduler, executable-jar

```
  public static void main(String[] test) {
        try {

            JobKey jobKeyA = new JobKey("JobAssignVehicleDailyrideFixedVehicle", "group1");
            JobDetail jobA = JobBuilder.newJob(JobAssignVehicleDailyrideFixedVehicle.class)
                    .withIdentity(jobKeyA).build();
            Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("Trigger1", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(
                            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
                    .build();
                    scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobA, trigger1);
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
```

I am running this method from main class from jar file.
How can i shutdown quartz properly without just terminating java processes.
Is there a way to call shutdown method on scheduler for current running quartz

Comment: Have you tried using `new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler()` in the other thread to obtain a reference to the scheduler started in the Main thread?

Comment: yes it worked thanks luc14n0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler()` in the Other thread to obtain a reference to the scheduler started in the Main thread.

Why does this work? Invocations of *StdSchedulerFactory#getScheduler* on both factory instances use the same *SchedulerRepository* singleton that contains a map of all running quartz schedulers, which in this case is just the default scheduler.

Comment: i could't understand this concept. you mean do i need watch exists of a file in another thread. if the file doesn't exist.. shutdown the quartz scheduler? Can you give some sample code here.